# Overriding default polynomial contrasts with ordered factors

Tags: r, regression, lm

Using an ordered factor as a predictor in a regression by default produces a linear (.L) and quadratic (.Q) polynomial contrast. Is there a way to omit the quadratic contrast? Here's some clumsy example code I rigged up:

```
xvar<-rnorm(100)
yvar<-x+rnorm(100)
xfac<-as.factor(c(1,2,3))

dat<-cbind(xvar,yvar,xfac)
dat<-data.frame(dat)
dat$xfac<-ordered(as.factor(dat$xfac))

summary(lm(yvar~xvar+xfac,data=dat))
```

Am I correct in assuming that the quadratic contrast being included as a predictor might result in some multicollinearity issues? I looked around but couldn't find any other posts about only including the linear component. Thank you!

Comment: would `summary(lm(yvar~xvar+as.numeric(xfac),data=dat))` do what you want?  I don't understand your concern about multicollinearity ...

Comment: The factor that I'm using isn't numeric, it's actually c("Computer","Avatar","Human"). I just tried converting it to an as.numeric and it changed the output very slightly--similar B and p values but different ones. My concern about multicollinearity: is including both a linear and quadratic version of the same predictor weakening each's effect on the outcome? Or am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: I think you're missing something fundamental (sorry).  There shouldn't be a multicollinearity problem, especially because `lm` uses orthogonal polynomials in this context.  I wasn't suggesting your variable should be numeric, but that if you wanted to do a linear model based on the ordered levels you should run a linear regression on the underlying numeric codes, which is what `as.numeric()` does.  This might be turning into a [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not correct. You would be correct if you had done this:

```
lm( yvar ~ xvar + as.numeric(xfac) +I(as.numeric(xfac)^2), data=dat)
```

But that's not the same as what R does when it encounters such a situation. Whether or not the quadratic term will "weaken" the linear estimate really depends on the data situation. If a quadratic fit reduces the deviations of fit from data, then the linear estimate might get "weakened", but not necessarily.

If you do want only the linear contrasts, you could do this (which is often called a "test of trend" for `xfac`):

```
lm( yvar ~ xvar + as.numeric(xfac), data=dat)
```

If you have an ordered factor with several levels and you only wanted the linear and quadratic contrasts then you can do this:

```
 > fac <- factor(c("E","VG","G","F","P"),  
                  levels=c("E","VG","G","F","P"), ordered=TRUE)
> sfac <- sample(fac, 30, rep=TRUE) 
> outcome <- 5*as.numeric(sfac) +rnorm(30) # linear outcome effect
> lm(outcome ~ sfac)
#-----------
Call:
lm(formula = outcome ~ sfac)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       sfac.L       sfac.Q       sfac.C       sfac^4  
   14.97297     15.49134      0.10634     -0.03287      0.40144  
#---------

> contrasts(sfac, 2) <- contr.poly(5)[, 1:2]
> lm(outcome ~ sfac)

Call:
lm(formula = outcome ~ sfac)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       sfac.L       sfac.Q  
   14.97078     15.50680      0.07977
```